# Do Javascript Event listeners get destroyed after firing (by default)?

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events, event-listener

I have an event listener on an object which fires a function when the object changes.

This is the code:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('campval').addEventListener("change", getscriptbuttons1());
```

This works perfectly the first time that the object changes however, all consecutive changes do not trigger the event listener.

Is this the normal behaviour of Javascript? What can I do to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, the event listener should get fired every time.

I think this error is due because you are calling the function instead of passing it as a parameter:

```
getscriptbuttons1 // passes the function
getscriptbuttons1() // calls the function and passes whatever it returns
```

---

Did you mean? :

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('campval').addEventListener("change", getscriptbuttons1);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not get destroyed. You have to remove them manually. The issue is that you are actually calling the function in the event listener. You need to change it to this: (no parens, don't call it)

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('campval').addEventListener("change", getscriptbuttons1);
```